# How to put the multiple images on the center of multiple backgrounds

Tags: css, html

How to center images both vertically and horizontally on background?

I have this code:

```css
.lineargradientgreen {
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, white);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.lineargradientblue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, white, blue);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineargradientgreen">
  <img src="https://www.listefit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/tiny-png-google-g%C3%B6rsel-optimizasyonu.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloon" width="200px" height="200px" />
</div>

<div class="lineargradientblue">
  <img src="https://www.samcodes.co.uk/project/geometrize-haxe-web/assets/images/xseagull.jpg.pagespeed.ic.iK66EGA15-.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloon" width="200px" height="200px" />
</div>
```

Finally, I got the images only horizontally centered on both backgrounds, how can I also vertically center them?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

> For **horizontal center** -> `justify-content:center` on parent
>
> For **vertical center** -> `align-self:center` on child

```css
.lineargradientgreen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, white);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.lineargradientblue {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, white, blue);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

div img {
  width: 300px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineargradientgreen">
  <img src="https://www.samcodes.co.uk/project/geometrize-haxe-web/assets/images/xseagull.jpg.pagespeed.ic.iK66EGA15-.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloon" />
</div>

<div class="lineargradientblue">
  <img src="https://www.listefit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/tiny-png-google-g%C3%B6rsel-optimizasyonu.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloon" />
</div>
```

### Flexbox Supported Browsers: When you search on Google

[image]

Comment: Cool, Thank you so much!!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Using flexbox is a good and modern solution, but you cannot use it if you want to support older browsers. I think that for the simple case in the question, it's an overkill as it can be easily done without flexbox and you don't need to worry about browser support.

Comment: If OP is quite precise about older browser, he definitely can't use Flex. But as it's not specified, flexbox is super handy. Your solution is great as well @RacilHilan :)

Comment: When you want to check the support for some CSS, JavaScript, or HTML feature, check a better website like [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) or MDN ;). w3school is also not bad, although many developers don't like it because it wasn't accurate in the past, and although it is much better now, they still hold their opinion against it.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, simply replace:

```
text-align: center;
```

with:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 150px;
```

Give it a padding that is half of the difference between the size of the box `500px` and the size of the image `200px`:

> 500 - 200 = 300 / 2 = 150.

```css
.lineargradientgreen {
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, white);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 150px;
}

.lineargradientblue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, white, blue);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineargradientgreen">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Hot Air Balloon" />
</div>

<div class="lineargradientblue">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Hot Air Balloon" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, like using it flexbox, display, position and etc. [centering css complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

For example using position: (**All older browsers support, like *IE*** :D)

```css
.lineargradientgreen {
  background-image: linear-gradient(green, white);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.lineargradientblue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, white, blue);
  border-width: 2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.myclass{
 position: relative;
}
.myclass > img{
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass lineargradientgreen">
  <img src="https://www.listefit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/tiny-png-google-g%C3%B6rsel-optimizasyonu.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloon" width="200px" height="200px" />
</div>

<div class="myclass lineargradientblue">
  <img src="https://www.samcodes.co.uk/project/geometrize-haxe-web/assets/images/xseagull.jpg.pagespeed.ic.iK66EGA15-.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloon" width="200px" height="200px" />
</div>
```

Comment: There is just no need to say "stupid". This is a website dedicated for programming questions and answers, so please keep it professional.

Comment: @RacilHilan OK, edited :d