# how to centre align div horizontally when using flex direction column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container that has a **table** and a **div** with the `display` set to `flex` with `flex-direction` as the `column`.

I want to align the div centre align horizontally. Here is the code

```
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .mytable {
        width: 100%
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .container2 {
        margin: 2.5em 0 0;
        display: flex;
        max-width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .question {
        padding: 5px 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 50%;
        background-color: green;
        border: 1px solid rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.2);
        border-top-left-radius: 18px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 18px;
        color: white;
    }

    .answer {
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.2);
        border-top-right-radius: 18px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <table class="mytable">
            <tr>
                <th>ABC</th>
                <th>DEF</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <span class="question">What is your Name</span>
        <span class="answer">Sunil Garg</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have tried `justify-content` and `align-items` CSS rules on the `container2` class. But these rules are not getting applied. What is the issue?

As the `text-align:center` is set to the `container2` class but still, its child div with class `answer` is not showing centre aligned text. what could be the possible issue?

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/er_markar/nznddv4k/

Thanks!!

Comment: try `margin:2.5em auto 0` in `.container2`

Comment: why you have a 2nd container inside your main container ? Isn't the question belong to column ABC and the answer to column DEF ??

Comment: @Bhuwan When using flexbox, you generally should use `justify-content` and `align-items` for alignment.

Comment: `align-items: center;` worked when I placed it in `.container2`. Here is your [editted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nznddv4k/26/). Perhaps you had an typo or used it in the wrong place?

Comment: @Tyler generally yes, but margin auto is used too. Bootstrap 4 use this a lot and it works pretty well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603779/7427111

Comment: @Tyler margin is also used to align the items. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties

Comment: @Tyler using justify-content and align-items are not working. Can you please verify on the provided fiddle?

Comment: @SunilGarg It works for me... What browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 11):

To align children within `flexbox`, set the following to the parent:

1- `justify-content` to align children along the main/primary axis i.e. *vertical* axis if parent has `flex-direction: column` and *horizontal* axis if parent has `flex-direction: row`.

2- `align-items` to align children along the cross/secondary axis i.e. *horizontal* axis if parent has `flex-direction: column` and *vertical* axis if parent has `flex-direction: row`.

In your case, try:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid red;
    justify-content: center; /* align children centered vertically */ 
    align-items: center; /* align children centered horizontally */
}
```

and remove `margin` from children that you are using to align children.